# please how do i use a method to store a collection of class objects using a dictionary for to store the items with appropriate keys and values

Tags: python, function, class, methods, iteration

class: Define a Python class(MovieList) with methods to do the following:

1. Define a constructor to create an object of the MovieList class.
2. A method to store a collection of movie objects that are created using the Movie class above. You should use a dictionary
   for to store the items with appropriate keys and values.
3. A method to search through the collection and find a movie by one or more of the following movie attributes: title, genre
   or release date.
4. A method to remove a movie from the collection based on the title of the movie.
5. A method to calculate and return the total number of movies stored in the collection.
6. You should include appropriate error checking and detailed comments in our code.

```
class MovieList:
    def __init__(self, name, maxMovieList):
        self.name = name
        self.maxMovieList = maxMovieList
        self.MovieCollection = []

    def add_movie(self, movie):
        if len(self.MovieCollection) < self.maxMovieList +1 :
            self.MovieCollection.append(movie)
            return True #if successfully added
        return False   #if not successfully added
    
    def find_movie(self, title):
        if self.title in MovieCollection:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, 
and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. 
Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and edit your post

Comment: `find_movie` return False ?

Answer (score 0):

As the instructions say, you should be storing the movies in a dictionary, not a list. Use the movie title as the key.

Instruction 3 says that the search method can take more than just the title. You can use keyword parameters, and then test if all the attributes match a movie. Use the `getattr()` method to retrieve an attribute dynamically.

```
class MovieList:
    def __init__(self, name, maxMovieList):
        self.name = name
        self.maxMovieList = maxMovieList
        self.MovieCollection = {}

    def add_movie(self, movie):
        if len(self.MovieCollection) < self.maxMovieList +1 :
            self.MovieCollection[movie.title] = movie
            return True #if successfully added
        return False   #if not successfully added
    
    def find_movie(self, **attributes):
        for movie in self.MovieCollection.values():
            if all(getattr(movie, key) == value for key, value in attributes):
                return movie
        return False
```